# Java - Can Hibernate choose between two database configurations in persistence.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, persistence

I have a **Java** app running on **Tomcat 7.0** with **Hibernate** managing the database.

I need to be able to switch the `jdbc.url` depending on a system environment variable (or possible another flag of sorts). Ultimately, I would like to be able to deploy a *staging* and *production* version of my webapp pointing to two different databases. However, at the moment, I have to physically change the `jdbc.url` value in `persistence.xml` and re-save it when switching between configurations.

My current `persistence.xml` file is:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="my_pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://my.rds.url.goes.here/mydatabase" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myusername" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypassword" />
            <property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I've read about using `createEntityManagerFactory()` as an option, but I can't find any clean examples of how to implement this. I'm certain this issue has been dealt with before, but I can't find a clean tutorial or advice.

How can I have my Hibernate switch database configurations without having to rewrite the `persistence.xml` file each time?

Comment: Create two persistence units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways to do it, if you use spring or maven in your project, could be:

With maven as your build tool, you can replace properties during build time based on a maven profile - through filtering in the maven resource plugin

If you use spring in your project the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer can inject the values for you. It can read the values as jvm parameters or from property files. These property files may be put in the tomcat/conf directory so each tomcat knows its own configuration, or you may build all possible properties, select them based on spring profile